# Does firebase limit on queries keep that limit even if I call the query again?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating a dating app and I'm trying to restrict the limit to one.  Once the person accepts or rejects the potential match I call the query again but it won't return anything.  I don't want to be charged if a user requests 100 documents and only browses one so I'd like to limit it to one then just recall the query again with the limit of one every time the user views one.

```js
  findMatching(selection) {

    const findMatchQuery = this.matchSvc.getMyMatches()
      .where('gender', '==', itinerary.searchGender)
      .orderBy('endDay')
      .limit(1);

    findMatchQuery.get()
      .then(itineraryListSnapshot => {

        itineraryListSnapshot.forEach(snapshot => {
          let age = moment().diff(snapshot.data().dateOfBirth, 'years');
            if ((age <= itinerary.ageRange.upper) && (age >= itinerary.ageRange.lower)) {
              this.matchingItineraries.push({
                id: snapshot.id,
                userId: snapshot.data().userId,         
                details: snapshot.data().details,
                searchGender: snapshot.data().searchGender,
                dateOfBirth: snapshot.data().dateOfBirth,
                photoUrl: '',
                displayName: snapshot.data().displayName
              });
            }
          }
        });
      })
```

So when a user swipes left or right I call the query again

```js
  rejectItinerary(user): void {
    this.matchingItineraries.splice(0, 1);
    this.findMatching(this.myTargetItinerary);
  }
```

The problem is once I reject a user and remove that user from the array and call the query again it doesn't return anything.  This is a strategy to reduce the db reads for pricing but is this not how the limit works?

The first time I call the query it works but the second time I call it nothing is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question/concern completely, so will instead explain how Firebase billing works in the scenario (as I understand it):

1. Every time you call `get()`, Firebase will have to check on the server for document(s) matching the query. This will cost at least 1 document read (even if there are no documents matched), and at most the number of documents returned.
2. Since your `findMatchQuery` limits to a single document, each call will cost 1 document read.
3. Each time you call `get()` on the `findMatchQuery` query, it is still limited to one document, so will return at most 1 document.
4. But since `get()` will need to check against the server, it will always cost 1 document read, even when there are no (more) matching documents.

Comment: So it's every time you call get()...not the number of documents returned in the get()?  Say you call get() and there are 1000 documents, that counts as 1000 document reads, right?

Comment: Every time the server reads a document for your project, you will be charged for one document read. If you `get()` 1,000 documents, that is 1,000 document reads. But your question uses a limit of 1, so it's always 1 charged document read.